# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (168, 5) but got array with shape (5808, 5)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I'm trying to implement a hybrid LSTM-DNN forecaster with multiple inputs using the code from Hvass-Labs Time Series tutorial #23. Basically I want to forecast day-ahead prices (just a 24 time step into the future for now) of electricity using sequential and non-sequential data. The model I'm using is two sets of inputs feeding an LSTM (for the sequential data) and Dense for the non-sequential data, with their outputs concatenated. It looks like this:

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiQol.jpg

Basically whenever I try to fit the model after one epoch it shows this error:

UPDATE:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (168, 5) but got array with shape (5808, 5)
```

The changes I have implemented:

```
# Chop off x_test_scaled into two parts:
x_test1_scaled = x_test_scaled[:,0:5] # shape is (5808, 5)
x_test2_scaled = x_test_scaled[:,5:12] # shape is (5808, 7)

validation_data = [np.expand_dims(x_test1_scaled, axis=0), np.expand_dims(x_test2_scaled, axis=0)], np.expand_dims(y_test_scaled, axis=0)
```

I'm confused because I have indeed assigned the generator to the generator in the model.fit_generator, and I'm not passing the x_test1_scaled which does have the shape of (5808, 5). edit:(not validation_data)

```
%%time
model.fit_generator(generator=generator,
                    epochs=10,
                    steps_per_epoch=30,
                    validation_data=validation_data,
                    callbacks=callbacks)
```

If this helps, this is my model:

```
# first input model
input_1 = Input(shape=((168,5)))
dense_1 = Dense(50)(input_1)

# second input model
input_2 = Input(shape=((168,7)))
lstm_1 = LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None, 7,))(input_2)

# merge input models
merge = concatenate([dense_1, lstm_1])
output = Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid')(merge)
model = Model(inputs=[input_1, input_2], outputs=output)
# summarize layers
print(model.summary())
```

---

EDIT: Cleared this problem, replaced with error on top.

Thus far I've managed everything up to actually fitting the model. 
Whenever an epoch finishes however it goes into the error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[[0.4       , 0.44444442, 0.        , ..., 0.1734707 ,
         0.07272629, 0.07110982],
        [0.3904762 , 0.43434343, 0.04347826, ..., 0.1740398 ,
         0.07282589, 0.06936309],
       ...
```

I have tried the solutions from other stackexchange posts of the same error message. They haven't been successful, but I was able to eventually isolate the problem array to that of the validation_data. I just don't know how to "reshape" it into the required 2 array.

The batch generator: I have included the two sets of inputs already. the x_batch_1 and x_batch_2

```
def batch_generator(batch_size, sequence_length):
    """
    Generator function for creating random batches of training-data.
    """

    # Infinite loop.
    while True:
        # Allocate a new array for the batch of input-signals.
        x_shape = (batch_size, sequence_length, num_x_signals)
        x_batch = np.zeros(shape=x_shape, dtype=np.float16)

        # Allocate a new array for the batch of output-signals.
        y_shape = (batch_size, sequence_length, num_y_signals)
        y_batch = np.zeros(shape=y_shape, dtype=np.float16)

        # Fill the batch with random sequences of data.
        for i in range(batch_size):
            # Get a random start-index.
            # This points somewhere into the training-data.
            idx = np.random.randint(num_train - sequence_length)

            # Copy the sequences of data starting at this index.
            x_batch[i] = x_train_scaled[idx:idx+sequence_length]
            y_batch[i] = y_train_scaled[idx:idx+sequence_length]

        x_batch_1 = x_batch[ :, :, 0:5]
        x_batch_2 = x_batch[ :, :, 5:12]
        yield ([x_batch_1, x_batch_2], y_batch)
```

```
batch_size = 32
sequence_length = 24 * 7
generator = batch_generator(batch_size=batch_size,
                            sequence_length=sequence_length)
```

Validation set:

```
validation_data = np.expand_dims(x_test_scaled, axis=0), np.expand_dims(y_test_scaled, axis=0)
```

And lastly the model fit:

```
%%time
model.fit_generator(generator=generator,
                    epochs=10,
                    steps_per_epoch=30,
                    validation_data=validation_data,
                    callbacks=callbacks)
```

```
ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[[0.4       , 0.44444442, 0.        , ..., 0.1734707 ,
         0.07272629, 0.07110982],
        [0.3904762 , 0.43434343, 0.04347826, ..., 0.1740398 ,
         0.07282589, 0.06936309],
       ...
```

The array is the same one as the validation_data. Another thing is that the error creeps up whenever the first epoch finishes which strengthens the case for the problem being the validation_data.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your model need 2 sets of input, `x_batch_1, x_batch_2` in your `batch_generator`. While your `validation_data` has only one array `np.expand_dims(x_test_scaled, axis=0)`

You need to make `validation_data` looks like the `batch_generator`, probably `[np.expand_dims(x_test1_scaled, axis=0), np.expand_dims(x_test2_scaled, axis=0)], np.expand_dims(y_test_scaled, axis=0)`.

In case of you still don't understand, please provide information about `x_test1_scaled`, like it's shape or how you load it.